# Como escribir el caracter # en un string de java

Tags: java

Intento hacer una app que llame a un código ussd de la empresa de telecomunicación en cuba (Etecsa) pero el código ussd es *222#, y cuando llamo sólo marca *222 y he notado que cuando escribo el símbolo de # el símbolo y lo que viene atrás no me sale que debo poner para remplazar # y que lo ponga en el string

Comment: Si no agregas el código que tienes va a ser difícil poder ayudarte.

Comment: Por favor haz el [tour] y lee [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida en la comunidad. Saludos

Comment: YA, YA vi que para marcar # en Java es con %23, debo escribir *222%23 para llamar al *222#